# How to check if property setter is public

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Given a PropertyInfo object, how can I check that the setter of the property is public?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Check what you get back from [`GetSetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ef4d5h3.aspx):

```
MethodInfo setMethod = propInfo.GetSetMethod();

if (setMethod == null)
{
    // The setter doesn't exist or isn't public.
}
```

Or, to put a different spin on [Richard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762456/c-how-to-check-if-property-setter-is-public/3762470#3762470):

```
if (propInfo.CanWrite && propInfo.GetSetMethod(/*nonPublic*/ true).IsPublic)
{
    // The setter exists and is public.
}
```

Note that if all you want to do is set a property as long as it has a setter, you don't actually have to care whether the setter is public. You can just use it, public *or* private:

```
// This will give you the setter, whatever its accessibility,
// assuming it exists.
MethodInfo setter = propInfo.GetSetMethod(/*nonPublic*/ true);

if (setter != null)
{
    // Just be aware that you're kind of being sneaky here.
    setter.Invoke(target, new object[] { value });
}
```

Comment: +1: This is better than `GetSetMethod().IsPublic`
: it also works when the property has *no* setter.

Comment: take a look at `IsAssembly()` in case you want to check if it's `internal set;`

Comment: Why would you sue `GetSetMethod(true).IsPublic` instead of `GetSetMethod()`? I don't understand the difference.

Answer (score 14):

.NET properties are really a wrapping shell around a get and set method.

You can use the `GetSetMethod` method on the PropertyInfo, returning the MethodInfo referring to the setter. You can do the same thing with `GetGetMethod`.

These methods will return null if the getter/setter is non-public.

The correct code here is:

```
bool IsPublic = propertyInfo.GetSetMethod() != null;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Program
{
    class Foo
    {
        public string Bar { get; private set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var prop = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar");
        if (prop != null)
        {
            // The property exists
            var setter = prop.GetSetMethod(true);
            if (setter != null)
            {
                // There's a setter
                Console.WriteLine(setter.IsPublic);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the underling method to determine accessibility, using [PropertyInfo.GetGetMethod()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getgetmethod.aspx) or [PropertyInfo.GetSetMethod()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getsetmethod.aspx).

```
// Get a PropertyInfo instance...
var info = typeof(string).GetProperty ("Length");

// Then use the get method or the set method to determine accessibility
var isPublic = (info.GetGetMethod(true) ?? info.GetSetMethod(true)).IsPublic;
```

Note, however, that the getter & setter may have different accessibilities, e.g.:

```
class Demo {
    public string Foo {/* public/* get; protected set; }
}
```

So you can't assume that the getter and the setter will have the same visibility.