# Creating custom attribute Entity Framework 5 for DateTime to be saved as UTC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to use the code given in this article

[Entity Framework DateTime and UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648540/entity-framework-datetime-and-utc)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DateTimeKindAttribute : Attribute
{
private readonly DateTimeKind _kind;

public DateTimeKindAttribute(DateTimeKind kind)
{
    _kind = kind;
}

public DateTimeKind Kind
{
    get { return _kind; }
}

public static void Apply(object entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        return;

    var properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || x.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?));

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var attr = property.GetCustomAttribute<DateTimeKindAttribute>();
        if (attr == null)
            continue;

        var dt = property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?)
            ? (DateTime?) property.GetValue(entity)
            : (DateTime) property.GetValue(entity);

        if (dt == null)
            continue;

        property.SetValue(entity, DateTime.SpecifyKind(dt.Value, attr.Kind));
    }
}
```

}

But I'm getting an error at

```
var attr = property.GetCustomAttribute<DateTimeKindAttribute>();
```

Error : The non-generic method 'System.Reflection.MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(bool)' cannot be used with type arguments

Any solutions???

Answer (score 3):

Just had the same problem, my solution was simply to add

```
using System.Reflection;
```

Answer (score 2):

With the code you posted, I would expect this:

> 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetCustomAttribute' and no extension method 'GetCustomAttribute'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo'
>   could be found

If you changed the code to this (i.e. make the call plural)

`var attr = property.GetCustomAttributes<DateTimeKindAttribute>();`

*then* you get the error you posted:

> The non-generic method
>   'System.Reflection.MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(bool)' cannot be
>   used with type arguments

The generic method used in the original answer is an extension in the [CustomAttributeExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace, and you need .NET 4.5