# Setting default dateTime value in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

So the problem is that I can't set the model so that the migration will show `DateTimeKind.Utc` instead of `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` 
I'm doing this:

```
contactsConfiguration
   .Property(c => c.DateAdded)
   .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
   .HasConversion(v => v, v => DateTime.SpecifyKind(v, DateTimeKind.Utc))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same problem and used https://stackoverflow.com/a/19301623/3937941 Hope it helps.

Comment: If you care about offsets use `DateTimeOffset` as a property and database field type, not `DateTime` with an *assumed* UTC value. `datetime` in the database has *no* indication that it's UTC or local (local to whom?).

Comment: BTW that migration has no meaning precisely because the `datetime` database type has no DateTimeKind.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{ 
   ... 

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes DateTime so if its Kind is Unspecified then it's set to Utc. 
    /// Does nothing on Serialization as SQL Server discards this info when saving to DateTime fields. 
    /// </summary>
    public class DateTimeToUtcConverter : ValueConverter<DateTime, DateTime>
    {
        public DateTimeToUtcConverter() : base(Serialize, Deserialize, null)
        {
        }

        static Expression<Func<DateTime, DateTime>> Deserialize = 
                x => x.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified ? DateTime.SpecifyKind(x, DateTimeKind.Utc) : x;
        static Expression<Func<DateTime, DateTime>> Serialize = x => x;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
    {
        // Configure ALL the DateTime properties in our EF model so they'll have DateTime.Kind set to Utc. 
        // (We'll also have to do this manually for any SQL queries we don't use EFCore to map to objects)
        configurationBuilder
            .Properties<DateTime>()
            .HaveConversion<DateTimeToUtcConverter>();
    }
}
```

I added a comment [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12994#issuecomment-1328107538), perhaps wiser people will reply with a better solution.

Comment: Ah, now I found basically the same thing here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73154546/8479