# How to pass Datetime parameter as string to web api controller (httpPut) PutAysnc

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-core-webapi

This is working: (but only date is getting passed to the API)

```
public async Task ConfirmFLSANotice(string mechNbr, DateTime AcceptedDate)
{
    await PutAsync("confirmflsanotice", mechNbr, AcceptedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}
```

Here I am passing just date but I want to pass time also, but no other format is working except this ("yyyy-MM-dd"). I've tried multiple ways.

**This is controller code:**

```
[JwtAuthentication]
[Route("api/login/confirmflsanotice/{mechNbr}/{AcceptedDate}/")]
[HttpPut]
public void ConfirmFLSANotice(string mechNbr, DateTime AcceptedDate)
{
    var proxy = DsRegistry.Current.GetService<IUserDsService>();
    proxy.ConfirmFLSANotice(mechNbr, AcceptedDate);
    DsRegistry.Current.CloseService(proxy);
}
```

I cannot change controller code.

Comment: Have you tried `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`?

Comment: Or just ToString();

Comment: I think you could check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60751537/11398810).

Comment: i tried this and multiple other format also. but its not working. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the date in a format that the `Binder` can interpret. Just pass `AcceptedDate.ToString("O")` which convert date time to a **ISO-8601** and this is the default format to pass date and time from one interface to other.

Also I recommend you to specify the type in the route, this avoids calls with invalid params:

```
[Route("api/login/confirmflsanotice/{mechNbr:int}/{AcceptedDate:datetime}/")]
```

Comment: i tried this but i will try again and let see. thanks

Comment: If that don´t work, maybe you should check the locale on both sides.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by passing the ticks and then converting those ticks into datetime on backend side

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by passing the ticks and then converting those ticks into datetime on backend side