# UI Date Picker Issue

Tags: c#, razor, kendo-ui, datepicker

I have an issue with date picker, here is the cshtml and cs code I have

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyDate)
                                <br />
                                @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.MyDate).Format("dd/MM/yyyy")
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyDateTime)
                                <br />
                                @Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(m => m.MyDateTime).Format("dd/MM/yyyy").HtmlAttributes(new { Placeholder = "Latest"})
                            </div>                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">MyButton</button>
                }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return MyFunc(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1).ConvertUtcToLocal(), null);
    }

public ActionResult MyFunc(DateTime theDate, DateTime? mydatetime)
    {
        //code not important

        return View("", new MyModel
        {
            MyDate = theDate.Date,
            MyDateTime= mydatetime
        });
    }
```

Convert Utc to local is custom method does as name suggests

Part 1: On first launch, I get 2/21/2024 in the controller Index method and 2/22/2024 gets passed on to MyFunc as we are adding one day. In the date picker UI I see 22/02/2024 which is what I want and latest in datetime picker but I want the date and time component.

Part 2: When I hit the button it calls the controller MyFunc with theDate as 1/1/0001. It seems because of mismatch between server and client, it expects Month first and obviously 22 is not a valid month. When I select a date say 03/09/2023 (3 September) the myFunc gets 3/9/2023 and assumes 3 to be month and makes it 09 March in the UI 09/03/2023.

I am unable to understand what is going wrong. Please tell me if information is missing I can add in the question.

Comment: Based on the cshtml code snippet in the question, seems like on the click of the button the 'MyMethod' action of 'MyControllerName' is going to be called. Is that a typing error or is some context missing here?

Comment: Could take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60720046/how-to-acccept-date-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-in-net-core-web-api

Comment: Method and Controller name sorry the name is not properly written, removed to avoid confusion

Comment: Will the chstml remain as is? I am confused how this will work for the first time when it calls Index and then myfunc subsequent times when button MyButton is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you are sending the date up in `dd/MM/yyyy` format but your server has a culture that is set to parsing the dates as `MM/dd/yyyy`.

If you want the web application to always parse the dates `MM/dd/yyyy`, regardless of which controller/action you're using then I would just change your `web.config` to match the culture you're using (e.g. `en-GB`):

```xml
<system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
</system.web>
```

Otherwise, if you only want to parse the dates `MM/dd/yyyy` on this one action, then a workaround is to replace the DateTime arguments as string arguments and then manually parse them at the top of the method:

```cs
public ActionResult MyFunc(string theDate, string mydatetime)
{
    DateTime theDateParsed;
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out theDateParsed))
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(theDate));
    }

    DateTime? myDateTimeParsed;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(mydatetime) && !DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out myDateTimeParsed))
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(mydatetime));
    }

    return View("", new MyModel
    {
        MyDate = theDateParsed.Date,
        MyDateTime = myDateTimeParsed
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be working fine locally. I will push my changes to app service and verify. Just a small thing for anyone else, I had .net core app so either you can have the globalization setting in appsettings.json and use it in startup ConfigureServices or directly specify default culture and UI culture within startup ConfigureServices

Comment: I do have one question: In layout we have: <html lang="@System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture"> and in startup app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("")//culture as you need            
        });