Ajax post request method binding failed in .NET 8 razor page
I am having issue: I am sending simple date and consumerid to my handler method through Ajax, but in the method, I'm always getting null. I think the issue is with the date.
Can anyone help me?
Client-side code:
consumer2.ConsumerId
var v1 = new Date();
var date = v1.getDate()+ "/" + (v1.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + v1.getFullYear();

// consumer2.datelocal = date;
console.log(consumer2);
console.log("------");
console.log(consumer);

$.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: getRootPath() + '/AjaxHandlers/Details?handler=UpdateConsumer2',
          headers: {
              'RequestVerificationToken': token
          },
            data: JSON.stringify(consumer2),
         // data: JSON.stringify({ Consumer: consumer2, UpdateConsumer: PartyUpdate, ChannelOfContactibility: "MAIL" }),
         // data: JSON.stringify( consumer ),
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

Web service method:
public class Consumer2
{
     public Nullable<DateTime> datelocal { get; set; }
     public int ConsumerId { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult OnPostUpdateConsumer2([FromBody] Consumer2 consumer) 
{
    return null;
}


Hi @rahul sing, can you share what is the value of consumer2 in your frontend?

hi @Rena it is assinged null

The Date object in JavaScript when formatted as dd/mm/yyyy might not be automatically recognized by .NET as a valid DateTime. To ensure proper parsing, use the yyyy-MM-dd format:
var consumer2 = {
    ConsumerId: 123, 
    datelocal: "" 
};
var v1 = new Date();
var date = v1.getFullYear() + "-" + (v1.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + v1.getDate();

consumer2.datelocal = date;


But cant we change the  date format according to our need ?

Hi @rahulsingh, of course you can, but if though you need custom model binding in server side to bind the different date format to data value. Refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/a/60751537/11398810

Hi Rena , the code you give it works , but since i am migrating from framework to .net 8 , previously it was working , but in core it is not

Hi @rahulsingh, .net core is quite different with .net framework.  It is not an extension of the older .NET framework.
