# Datetime Conflict (dd/mm/yyyy) in server

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, razor-pages, bootstrap-datepicker

When i uploaded my razor pages application to server always getting this error 'The value '14/09/2022' is not valid for ...*.' i could figure out the issue,the format is interpreted as mm/dd/yyyy. i could not change the system dateformat for my server.

So what i did is i changed my applications Culture and UI-Culture Via IIS manager.

[image]

Even after that changes,its still showing the same issue.Im using Bootstrap datepicker.
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

******************Edited******************

Startup.cs

```
public class CustomDateConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
        {
            public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
            {
                Debug.Assert(typeToConvert == typeof(DateTime));
                return DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString());
            }

            public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
            {
                writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToUniversalTime().ToString("dd'/'mm'/'yyyy"));
            }
        }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddDebug()))
                    .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
            services.AddRazorPages().AddJsonOptions(options =>{
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new CustomDateConverter());
            });
            services.AddMemoryCache();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post dates to the server in ISO 8601 format, which is `yyyy-mm-dd`. If you want to use a different format in the datepicker, you can use a hidden field to store a version of the date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. You can use the `onchange` event of the date picker to populate the hidden field.

Or, if you can restrict the browser used to Chrome, Edge or Opera, you can just use an HTML5 input `type="datetime-local"` instead:

https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/352/working-with-dates-and-times-in-razor-pages-forms

Comment: .My application works fine in my localhost where the system dateformat is dd/mm/yyyy. The system dateformat of my server where the application is deployed is mm/dd/yyyy,which i cannot change because of someother projects dependencies.

Comment: Yes - that's why you should work with ISO 8601 formats. Then  you don't have to worry about regional settings on different servers.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution to set the date time format at server side is to setup the localization settings in startup:

```cs
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationSettings>(ops => 
{
    var cultures = new CultureInfo[] { new CultureInfo("en-GB") }
    ops.SupportedCultures = cultures;
    ops.SupportsUICultures = cultures;
    ops.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB");
});
```

Then use localization middleware:

```cs
app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

Or you may set date format manually for a specific page:

```cs
var myCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
myCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/mm/yyyy";

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = myCulture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = myCulture;
```

Or you may create a [custom converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58103218/5519026) and configure it globally:

```cs
services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        ops.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new CustomDateConverter()));
    });
```

And of course don't forget to set the date format in [bootstrap datetime picker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format) as well:

```js
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

Comment: Hi @Laz Ziya, I tried to use the third option.But it showing like 'JsonOptions doesnot contain a definition for serializer settings'. i tried to use  services.AddRazorPages() ,but still showing same error.Do i need to install anyother packages?

Comment: Hi @Teena, I've updated my answer (third option) to be compatible with razor pages and `System.Text.Json`, previously it was for `Mvc` and `NewtonsoftJson`.

Comment: hi @Laz Ziya , I changed accordingly still the date validation error is showing. I have updated my startup.cs file with DateTimeConverter function,and changed the rest of the code.But still its showing the same error for date.

Comment: I have edited my question.Could you please let me know if im doing anything wrong in that.

Comment: In your post, I did not find the DateTimeConverter function, how did you do it?

Comment: Hi @Teena, you will implement your own, the link already provided in the post.

Comment: @samwu Hi, In my post i renamed it as CustomDateConverter. And im facing the issue when im editing the records. When im adding i dont face any issues.

Comment: @Laz Ziya, i implemented my own functions by referring the codes in the link you provided. Still that error is showing.

Comment: @Teena Maybe you need to set the date format on the Control Panel, more information you can refer to this link: [https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/How-to-set-Date-and-time-format-in-IIS-Manager](https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/How-to-set-Date-and-time-format-in-IIS-Manager).