# Date issues using Angular calling .net core web API and SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, angular, date, datetime, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using Angular and primeng p-calendar to provide me with a date picker to select a date in the past. When I save a date like the 24 Nov 82 it saves it in the database as shown below. I believe I am saving the dates as UTC, but when I save a date of the 19 Nov 1943 it puts the data to the 18th because, it is taking away an hour. When I load the 19th up back in the p-calendar it puts the date as the 18th and not the 19th?

[image]

Am I saving this incorrectly? or do I need to think about handling it when I load the date back up? e.g. do I need to take the UTC and convert it to my browsers timezone?

For the 24 Nov 1982 I get this when I debug the angular side:

[image]

For the 18 Nov 1943 I get this when I debug the angular side:

[image]

I have hear mention of dayjs, would this solve my problem?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you show your api that saves gata?

Comment: Ahh yes I have figured it out, the .net core web api is not returning the dates as UTC (Zulu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the .net core web API, it was retuning the dates without UTC details. I implemented the DateTimeConveter as shown here:

[Formatting DateTime in ASP.NET Core 3.0 using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58102189/formatting-datetime-in-asp-net-core-3-0-using-system-text-json)

```
public class DateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString());
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZ"));
    }
}


// in the ConfigureServices()
services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
     {
         options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
     });
```

The dates now have a Z (Zulu) at the end to signify UTC e.g.

```
1943-11-18T23:00:00Z
```

instead of the previous date like this

```
1943-11-18T23:00:00
```

The Date is now shown as the 19th instead of the 18th in the p-calendar

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `DateTime`, which is implicitly non-timezone-aware, instead of `DateTimeOffset` which is. Change your code to use the latter and it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Ill give that a go, much appreciated