# How to get the public writable properties of a class

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, reflection, system.reflection

Very similar to [How to get all public both get and set properties of a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824802/c-how-to-get-all-public-both-get-and-set-string-properties-of-a-type)

Suppose I have a simple class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int A {get; set;}
    public int B {get; private set;}
    public int C {get; set;}

    public MyClass() {... sets this.A and this.B}
}
```

Using reflection I want the sequence of all properties that I can write values to. The following is incorrect:

```
var allWritableProperties = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties()
    .Where(property => property.CanWrite);
```

- Method GetProperties correctly returns only the public properties B and C.
- Property B has a private Set, so I can't write to it.
- Yet B CanWrite is true, therefore the Where Function will return B and C.
- I can only write to C, therefore I want only C

For those who want to know why I want to do this. I have a class with that implements IEquality. I have a unit test that tests whether this is implemented correctly. Recently someone added a property but forgot to change the Equals function. Therefore some different objects were considered to be equal. My unit test should have warned about this.

Therefore I want to change the test such that it changes all public writable properties one by one and checks if Equals returns false. In that case if someone added a public writable property but forgot to use check it in Equals the test would fail.

Comment: Because `CanWrite` doesn't check the `set` accessibility, but just whether it exists. `GetGetMethod()` does only return the setter when it exists _and_ is public, see [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762456/c-sharp-how-to-check-if-property-setter-is-public). :) So something like `GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetSetMethod(false) != null)`. If that doesn't answer your question I may have misunderstood, feel free to @ping me and I'll reopen as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks, should I delete this question?

Comment: No, you don't have to, really. Differently phrased questions leading to the same answers is a good thing. :)